# Using ActiveMQ via JNDI

Tags: java, jndi, activemq-classic

I'm trying to create simply connect with ActiveMQ using JNDI.

I have:

1. Queue named `example.A`.
2. According [ActiveMQ documentation touching JNDI](http://activemq.apache.org/jndi-support.html), if I want to use ConectionFactories and Queues (Topics) via JNDI, I have to place `jndi.properties` file on my classpath. As I have understood, ActiveMQ classpath is `%activemq%/conf` directory by default. I have not changed it. So I have this property for my queue:

   ```
   queue.MyQueue = example.A
   ```
3. I have created java client class for ActiveMQ which uses JNDI as below:

   ```java
   Properties jndiParameters = new Properties() ;
   jndiParameters.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
   jndiParameters.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "tcp://localhost:61616");
   Context context = new InitialContext(jndiParameters);
   ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
   Queue queue = (Queue) context.lookup("MyQueue");
   ```

But it cannot find my queue. It throws exception:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: MyQueue
```

Where are my mistakes?

Comment: I have a similiar problem, I can configure the jndi url and connection factory but I cannot provide additional properties. This way it seems the Queue endpoint is not defined. It works if I use dynamicQueue/Test, but should it also be possible to address staticly named destinations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are explicitly creating the properties and passing them into the InitialContext constructor. This means the jndi.properties on the class path won't be read.

Your code should be something like:

```
Context context = new InitialContext();
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
Queue queue = (Queue) context.lookup("MyQueue");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set static properties as well as retrieve them from a file as such:

```
    InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/my.jndi.properties");
    Properties jndiParameters = new Properties();
    jndiParameters.load(is);
    jndiParameters.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
    jndiParameters.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "tcp://localhost:61616");
    Context ctx =  new InitialContext(jndiParameters);
...
```

This works as long as you set the static props after you load the resource. Helpful if you're loading the provider url from somewhere else for instance.