# ActiveMQInitialContextFactory vs. NamingContextFactory

Tags: java, jndi, activemq-classic

I'm creating a java enterprise application which uses activemq to send messages to a standalone queue broker.

I currently maintain access to long lived resources through jndi lookup which works quite nicely. I'd like to continue this pattern with the ActiveMQ connection factories and queue connection factories, however in the [amq documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/jndi-support.html) it specifies that my jndi.properties should have:

```
java.naming.factory.initial = org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
```

while the default jndi.properties (which works with my simple object and facade lookups has:

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
```

Can I use one with the other? Can I have two jndi.properties files or two initial contexts somehow?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453561/using-activemq-via-jndi) question shows how to configure ONLY activemq through jndi. I want them to play nicely together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create any number of `InitialContext` objects you want. You just have to pass environment to its [constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/naming/InitialContext.html#InitialContext%28java.util.Hashtable%29) to properly initialize it.

So you can still safely use `jndi.properties` and initialize initial context for activemq with the code which may look like this:

```
public void setUpActiveMQResources() throws IOException, NamingException {
    InitialContext context = createInitialContext("/activemq.jndi.properties");
    // do what you want
}

public InitialContext createInitialContext(String resource) throws IOException, NamingException {
    InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(resource);
    Properties props = new Properties();
    try {
        props.load(is);
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
    return new InitialContext(props);
}
```

`activemq.jndi.properties` in that case is the classpath resource with content like [here](http://activemq.apache.org/jndi-support.html)

Comment: awesome, can't wait to try this out.