# ActiveMQ JNDI Lookup Issues

Tags: java, jboss, jndi, activemq-classic

Trying to get ActiveMQ with JNDI running following ([http://activemq.apache.org/jndi-support.html](http://ActiveMQ%20JNDI)) and i have all the required activeMQ jars in my jboss/server/node/lib folder and my jndi.properties looks like:

```
java.naming.factory.initial = org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory

# use the following property to configure the default connector
java.naming.provider.url = vm://localhost

# use the following property to specify the JNDI name the connection factory
# should appear as. 
#connectionFactoryNames = connectionFactory, queueConnectionFactory, topicConnectionFactry
connectionFactoryNames = connectionFactory

# register some queues in JNDI using the form
# queue.[jndiName] = [physicalName]
queue.MyQueue = TESTQUEUE


# register some topics in JNDI using the form
# topic.[jndiName] = [physicalName]
topic.MyTopic = example.MyTopic
```

and have following piece of code in producer which actually produces the call:

```
InitialContext ic = null;
ConnectionFactory factory = null;
Connection con = null;
Session session = null;
Queue queue = null;
MessageProducer producer = null;

ic = new InitialContext();
factory = (ConnectionFactory) ic.lookup("connectionFactoryNames");
con = factory.createConnection();
session = con.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
queue = (Queue)ic.lookup("queue/TESTQUEUE");
producer = session.createProducer(queue);
// Then... send the message.
producer.send(session.createObjectMessage(new Long(Id)));
```

and here is the exception am getting, not sure what does it mean by `scheme java not recognized`

```
WARN org.jboss.system.ServiceController - Problem starting service jboss:service=Naming
javax.naming.NamingException: scheme java not recognized
    at org.apache.activemq.jndi.ReadOnlyContext.lookup(ReadOnlyContext.java:221)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at org.jboss.naming.NamingService.startService(NamingService.java:274)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
    at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:435)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:302)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:482)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:490)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

This question moved me in proper direction: [ActiveMQInitialContextFactory vs. NamingContextFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143843/activemqinitialcontextfactory-vs-namingcontextfactory)

Comment: let me know if more information is needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get it up and running, issue was that i had one `jndi.properties` file and in that file i have standard,

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces
```

and as we were already using jndi in our application, i could not go ahead an modify files present here and also cannot add my `activemq` related changes in here and so solution was to create different `jndi.properties` file for `activemq` and get new `initialcontext` to it as mentioned in [ActiveMQInitialContextFactory vs. NamingContextFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143843/activemqinitialcontextfactory-vs-namingcontextfactory) and other thing had to make sure is that i have same broker information for both producer and sender side, which is obvious and it worked fine.

Adding information so that next time someone lands up on this question then he or she does not have to spend time which i have already spend figuring this thing out. Hope this would help.