# NameNotFoundException while QueueConnectionFactory lookup

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, activemq-classic, jndi

I have got a running GlassFish-Server (Version 4.1). Now I am interested in creating a simple messaging service using jms and a standalone messaging client. (this should run on a remote machine in a separate JVM.) Unfortunately I still get a NameNotFoundException when I attempt to initialize my QueueConnectionFactory.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.jms.*;
import javax.naming.Context;

public class TestJMSQueue {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    String msg = "Hello from remote JMS Client";

    test.sendMessage2Queue(msg);

    System.exit(0);
  }

  private void sendMessage2Queue(String msg) throws Exception {

    props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
    props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "mq://localhost:7676");
    props.put("connectionFactoryNames" , "TestQueueConnectionFactory");
    props.put("queue." + "TestQueue", "TestQueue");

    InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);
    System.out.println("Context created");

    ConnectionFactory qFactory = (ConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup("TestQueueConnectionFactory");

    Connection connection = qFactory.createConnection();

    Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

    TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
    message.setJMSDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
    message.setText(msg);

    Queue queue = (Queue) ctx.lookup("TestQueue");

    MessageProducer mp = session.createProducer(queue);

    mp.send(message);
    System.out.println("Message sent: " + msg);

    mp.close();
    session.close();
    ctx.close();
  }
}
```

The Factory and the Queue exist on the server.

I am following [this tutorial](http://techtipsjava.blogspot.co.at/2013/05/jms-on-glassfish-queue-and-topic-with.html) and already created the listener for the server.
I spent the last hours looking at various resources, trying to resolve the problem, but I didn't find a solution.

Can you please tell me where I went wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Here are a few of the resources I have been looking at:

- [Using ActiveMQ via JNDI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453561/using-activemq-via-jndi)
- [ActiveMQInitialContextFactory vs. NamingContextFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143843/activemqinitialcontextfactory-vs-namingcontextfactory)
- [ActiveMQ JNDI Lookup Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528102/activemq-jndi-lookup-issues)
- http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/JMSProducer/JMSProducer.html
- https://www.javatpoint.com/jms-tutorial

**EDIT:**

I also tried it with a jndi.properties file instead of the props.put(...) and the InitialContext(props). And with the adding the following before the InitialContext instantiation:

```
properties.put("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "<IP>");
properties.put("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
//as found [here...][2]
//But as I understand it the solution with 3700 is not for JMS so I also tried it with 7676
```

Didn't work either.

The error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create Transport. Reason: java.io.IOException: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [mq]
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:33)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createTransport(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:232)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:245)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:214)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:161)
    at testjmsqueue.TestJMSQueue.sendMessage2Queue(TestJMSQueue.java:60)
    at testjmsqueue.TestJMSQueue.main(TestJMSQueue.java:30)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [mq]
    at org.apache.activemq.util.IOExceptionSupport.create(IOExceptionSupport.java:25)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.findTransportFactory(TransportFactory.java:171)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.connect(TransportFactory.java:76)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createTransport(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:230)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not find factory class for resource: META-INF/services/org/apache/activemq/transport/mq
    at org.apache.activemq.util.FactoryFinder.doFindFactoryProperies(FactoryFinder.java:90)
    at org.apache.activemq.util.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:58)
    at org.apache.activemq.util.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:47)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.findTransportFactory(TransportFactory.java:167)
    ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
    props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
    props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "mq://localhost:7676");
    props.put("connectionFactoryNames" , "TestQueueConnectionFactory");
    props.put("queue." + "TestQueue", "TestQueue");
    InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(props);
    ConnectionFactory qFactory = (ConnectionFactory) ic.lookup("TestQueueConnectionFactory");
    Queue  queue  = (Queue ) ic.lookup("TestQueue");
```

Comment: a different error occurred: `Exception in thread "main" javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create Transport. Reason: java.io.IOException: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [mq]`

Comment: It occurred at `Connection connection = qFactory.createConnection();`

Comment: i have updated my answer, yeah what is this mq transport ??

Comment: you use a standalone ActiveMQ ?? in this case your url is tcp://localhost:61616

Comment: yes is it but you have to update the url to props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "tcp://localhost:61616");

Comment: Okay with the tcp thing I am getting a `ConnectException: Connection refused: connect` Is this the server config or do I have to change the code?

Comment: did you have changed the default activemq.xml ?? transportConnector port or added authorizationPlugin ??  do not forget to rename  jndi.properties to discard it

Comment: How would I do it without a standalone MQ? If there is a solution without having to install that that would be great...

Comment: Standalone AMQ is better solution for performance ! But you can embedd it easily but it is better standalone. It is easy to install by only unzipping and starting it http://activemq.apache.org/installation.html

Comment: Thank you very much; you are a lifesaver: my ActiveMQ installation was broken; I reinstalled it and tested it with the solution you provided and it worked :)